# Simplify complex integral using parity

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I am really confused by a result Mathematica is giving, and I am wondering if this is a bug or a feature (i.e. if there is some math behind the result).

I ask it to compute 
$$
I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{x(1+a x- a^2)}{(x-a)^2}e^{-\frac{x^2}2},
$$
where the imaginary part of $a$ is positive, which I know, using other means of integration,
$$
I_{exact}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} e^{-\frac{a^2}{2}} \left(i-\text{erfi}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right),
$$
where $\text{erfi}$ is the imaginary error function.

Now, when asked to do the integral, Mathematica gives 
$$
I_M=\frac{1}{2} (a^2-1)  \left(2 a-\sqrt{2 \pi } \left(a^2-1\right) e^{-\frac{a^2}{2}}
   \left(\text{erfi}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-i\right)\right),
$$
which is different (i.e. it takes different values than $I$ when evaluated for a specific value of $a$). (Note that if I tell Mathematica to take $a$ to be a specific value (say $a=2i$) then integrate, it then evaluates to the correct value...)

Multiplying the integrand by $\frac{(x+a)^2}{(x+a)^2}$, which I think is allowed since there is no singularity there, and then throwing away all terms odd in $x$ in the numerator, which I think is also allowed, the integral can be rewritten as
 $$
I'=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{a x^4+(2a-a^3)x^2}{(x^2-a^2)^2}e^{-\frac{x^2}2},
$$
which Mathematica is now able to compute correctly.

So the question is : Is there any subtility when simplifying this integral, or is Mathematica just buggy here ?

Comment: I checked integral on Mathematica version `11.3` and works fine.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk You checked the first integral ? Then it must be a bug they corrected after 11.0 (I tried on 11.0 and 10.0).